# Лучший способ для долгосрочного хранения данных

Tags: android

Как лучше хранить небольшие объемы данных в Android. Я знаю, что все можно в базе хранить, но мне в моей программе нужно хранить лишь один массив. Я думал сделать это через сериализацию, но может быть можно сделать через `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Действительно лучше sharePreferences, как и для настроек (кстати). Пример, который может вам подойти: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android, теория: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php

Answer (score 0):

Массивы можно хранить в ресурсах: `res/values/xml-file.`
Внутри него в тегах resources создаешь массив, например:

```
<string-array name="array1">
<item>элемент массива </item>
</string-array>
```

Но все же, удобнее будет использовать SharedPreferences